# Lebesgue measure of difference of two translations of a set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $C$ be a bounded measurable set on $\mathbb{R}$ and $m$ be Lebesgue measure.
Compute  $\lim\limits_{a\to b} m[(C + a )\setminus(C + b)]$, where $C+a=\{c+a| c\in C\}$ is a translation of $C$.

I got the result with $C$ is an interval $(x,y)$ whose result is $\lim\limits_{a\to b} m[(C + a )\setminus(C + b)]=0$, but not in general case $C$ is bounded. I guess it should be zero also.

How could I deal with the general case? Could you give me a hint? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any $\epsilon >0$ there exist disjoint intervals $(a_i,b_i]$ such that $m (C \Delta (\cup_i (a_i,b_i])) <\epsilon$. A proof of this basic approximation thoerem can be found in Halmos's Measure Theory book. [See Theorem D page 56].  Hence,  the required limit is $0$. [Note that $((a_i,b_i]+a)\setminus ((a_i,b_i]+b)$ are disjoint].